# Unable to read file from Project's root folder in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, file-manager

I have placed a file inside my App's Root folder. The path of the file would be like *"/Users/MyUser/Documents/MyApp/ios/TestFolder/AppConfigKeyFile".* I want to read this file at runtime. Below is the code which I have written in AppDelegate to fetch the file

```
        let testFolderURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: #file)
        .deletingLastPathComponent()
        .deletingLastPathComponent()
        .appendingPathComponent("TestFolder", conformingTo: .folder)

    let appConfigKeysFileUrl = testFolderURL.appendingPathComponent("AppConfigKeyFile")
    print(appConfigKeysFileUrl)

    do {
        let appconfigKeysData = try Data(contentsOf: appConfigKeysFileUrl)
        cancellable = MyJsonDecoder.decode(from: appconfigKeysData).sink { error in
            switch error {
            case .finished:
                break
            case .failure(let failure):
                print(failure.localizedDescription)
            }
        } receiveValue: { (appConfigKeys: AppConfigKeys) in
            print(appConfigKeys.myKey)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

This code works as expected on Simulator. But when I try to run it on actual device it gives me following error *"The file “AppConfigKeyFile” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."*
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Use `Bundle` instead to get a URL to your file since this file is part of your app bundle, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1411540-url

Comment: File is not a part of my app bundle. It is placed outside the bundle. So basically this "TestFolder" will be added to my project's root directory when I create a build using build machine. I don't want to disclose the key in github, so it won't be a part of my app bundle.

Comment: If the file isn't part of your app bundle then it won't exist on the device when the app is installed. The app bundle is the only thing that is delivered to a device. Whether or not you add it to GitHub is a different matter, but you must add the file to your bundle if you want it to be available at runtime.

Comment: @Paulw11 I understand your point here. But I am failing to understand how come it is available for simulator then ?

Comment: Because for the simulator the file isn't in the app bundle since the app run by the simulator has a completely different path. It's somewhere under ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/

Comment: The simulator is just that; a simulator. It is just a program running on your Mac, so it can access file system of your Mac.  The app running on a real device cannot access the file system of your Mac. It is running in a sandboxed environment on the iOS device. It can only access files in its sandbox. The files in the sandbox are the bundle plus whatever files the app itself creates